# Moving folders to alphabetically catalogued folders by using a batch-file

Tags: batch-file

I want to move folders to alphabetically catalogued folders by using a batch-file, eg.:

Move folders starting with an "A" to folder "A", folders starting with a "B" to folder "B" etc. Numerical folders have to go to folder "#".

I've come up with this but it only works for files and I can't get it to work for folders.
I have to change the %%~A*.* into something else but I don't know into what...

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

FOR %%A IN %Letters% DO MOVE "%%~A*.*" "%%~A\"
FOR %%B IN %Numbers% DO MOVE "%%~B*.*" "#\"
```

I have created the letter-folders already so creating those folders is not necessary.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I was almost with you until after your code, _(apart from what happens to files which do not begin with an alphabet or number character)_. Then suddenly you mentioned that you'd already created the alphabet character directories. How do you expect to move a directory into itself? BTW, pre-setting the numbers and letters isn't necessary, you can simply take the first character of each file's name and move the directories using those.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you remove the `.*` it should move directories as well.  "folder" is too modern for me... :)  but that's what I meant...

Comment: Some clarification for you. I want to move directories starting with an A (eg. Alpha and Ape) to folder A and that for folders starting with all letters. A simple "Move A* A" does not work in a batch file i found out. Don't know why but wildcards in directories don't work this way, at least not on my laptop ;-)...

Answer (score 1):

This is untested, but may provide a solution based upon to my understanding of the question, *with no comment response*, as it existed at the time of this answer:

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" ^
    /I "^[0123456789a-Z]" ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I /V "%~nx0"') Do @(
    Set "Object=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If "%%~aG" GEq "d" (If Not "!Object:~1,1!" == "" "%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe"^
     "%%~G" "!Object:~,1!\%%G" /E /Move >NUL 2>&1
    ) Else "%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" . "!Object:~,1!" "%%G" /Mov >NUL 2>&1
    EndLocal)
```

If you really did want to send the numeric objects to a directory named `#`, perhaps this untested modification of the above would be sufficient for your needs:

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A ^| "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /I "^[0123456789a-Z]" ^| "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I /V "%~nx0"') Do @(Set "Object=%%G" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If "%%~aG" GEQ "d" (If Not "!Object:~1,1!" == "" (If "!Object:~,1!" GEQ "0" If "!Object:~,1!" LEQ "9" ("%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%~G" "#\%%G" /E /Move >NUL 2>&1) Else "%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" "%%~G" "!Object:~,1!\%%G" /E /Move >NUL 2>&1)) Else If "!Object:~,1!" GEq "0" If "!Object:~,1!" LEq "9" ("%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" . # "%%G" /Mov >NUL 2>&1) Else "%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" . "!Object:~,1!" "%%G" /Mov >NUL 2>&1
    EndLocal)
```

Comment: Wow, this works! I would never come up with this and can't understand what you're doing but hey, it works! Thanks!   The only thing it does "wrong" is that it places number directories into the corresponding starting number in stead of moving it to folder # but if that's all than so be it!

Comment: However, it takes a long time if the directory is rather big like mine which is 150 Gb now.

Comment: I've added an additional answer to the above, @RemovanVuuren, to cater for the numeric to # stipulation. As for the speed, feel free to create a faster version yourself, or accept another answer which performs the same task and does it quicker.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I didn't mean to insult you...

Comment: I'm not insulted @RemovanVuuren, your question made no mention of the number and size of files, it was trying to perform a task only, and that is how I answered it. As for size of files, that shouldn't matter as you're only moving within the same drive and path, if you have a lot of files then obviously, as you're iterating them one by one, then there's more work to do, and more work takes longer than less. When you ask a question, and it is answered, you should not make a decision to accept that answer based upon factors which did not form part of the question at the time it was answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /ad "filepath"') do (
  set fn=%%a
  for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if /i "%fn:~0,1%"=="%%b" move "%fn%" " %%b\"
  for /l %%c in (1,1,9) do if "%fn:~0,1%"=="%%c" move "%fn%" "%%c\"
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your your reply! I copied your code into an empty batch file but it doesn't do anything. My knowledge of coding is limited. I can follow what you're doing but is a character misplaced maybe? I can't figure that out...

Comment: Replace "filepath" with the path of files in the code in first line

Comment: That's what I did. I think you don't even need to address the filepath if you perform the command from within the source directory. I really want this to work but it doesn't on my Windows 10 laptop. I see that you compare the first letter of the directories to a letter in %%b and that you then move the compared directory to that letter directory. I follow that and it should work but alas... nothing...